# Correct layout of h:outputLabel and rich:combobox components on same line

Tags: jsf, layout, richfaces, seam

With richfaces, how can I get my `h:outputLabel` and `rich:combobox` components to display directly adjacent to each other on the same line?

Here are the two approaches I've tried.

---

**#1 rich:Layout**
I first tried using `rich:layout` & `rich:layoutPanel`, but the components appear on separate lines. Here's the code:

```
<rich:layout>
  <rich:layoutPanel position="left" width="100%">
    <h:outputLabel for="timeSpanUnitsCombo2" value="Time Span " />
    <rich:comboBox id="timeSpanUnitsCombo2" value="#{bean.timeSpanUnitsLabel}" enableManualInput="false">       
      <f:selectItems value="#{bean.timeSpanUnitsList}" />
    </rich:comboBox>
  </rich:layoutPanel>
</rich:layout>
```

And here's the rendered output:

[image]

---

**#2 h:panelGrid**
Next I tried using a `h:panelGrid`, but again no success - the components are evenly spaced over the available area, instead of being directly adjacent and left-aligned as I intended. Here's the code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
  <h:outputLabel for="timeSpanUnitsCombo3" value="Time Span " />
  <rich:comboBox id="timeSpanUnitsCombo3" value="#{bean.timeSpanUnitsLabel}" enableManualInput="false">       
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.timeSpanUnitsList}" />
  </rich:comboBox>
</h:panelGrid>
```

And here's the rendered output:

[image]

---

*Component layout with richfaces is proving to be thoroughly frustrating. I'll give second prize to anyone who has some good references on layout with richfaces. :)*

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by many ways. One of them is to use fragment

```
<s:fragment>
      <h:outputText value="Time Span" />
      <rich:comboBox id="timeSpanUnitsCombo2" value="#{bean.timeSpanUnitsLabel}" enableManualInput="false">       
            <f:selectItems value="#{bean.timeSpanUnitsList}" />
      </rich:comboBox>
</s:fragment>
```

Or you can use a div instead of fragment. `<div> your code...</div>`

Comment: I don't see how s:fragment can help in this matter

Comment: Shervin you are right, my mistake. A div with h:outputText or a span with h:outputText may help here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using seam, you can wrap it in `<s:decorate>` and use `<s:label>`

From Seam in Action

`....<s:label> and <s:message>. The benefit of using the Seam tags is
that they are automatically correlated with the adjacent input component, a feature
of <s:decorate>`